# Literally Riley

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, language

My prefix sounds of lines
My infix's on signs
My suffix's hat's askew
I'm Spanish, it's true

What word am I?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you might be:

> the Spanish word **Qué?**, meaning 'What?'

*My prefix sounds of lines*

> Your prefix is simply, '**Q**', which sounds like 'queue' - a synonym of 'line'.

*My infix's on signs*

> Your infix is '**U**' - a letter used on road-signs to signify where a U-turn is or isn't permitted.

*My suffix's hat's askew*

> Your suffix is '**É**' - a letter which looks like it's wearing a little hat at a jaunty angle.

*I'm Spanish, it's true*

> The word 'Qué' is Spanish.

As for the title:

> Well, when you ask us "***What*** word am I?!", you *literally* mean it - you are the word 'What'... just in a different language!

Comment: What a literal answer!